# js ignores the condition

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ((screen.width==240) )
{
 $('.verybig').hide();
}
else
{ 
  $('.verybig').show();
}
});
```

I want mobile devices with a screen of 240px to hide class "verybig" of ui elements. Does the above look like a correct condition?
I can not find any pattern in the way the code behaves in totally unpredictible ways.

Comment: Try to `console.log(screen.width)` and tell us the result

Comment: The condition looks fine, however badly formatted.

Comment: Note that the global `screen` object is part of the DOM0 (no W3C specification) and even though being supported by all major browsers, theoretically not every browser may support it. Your best bet is using `console.log` as jerome said, or, as you're testing on mobile, append the value to the page. Try running this fiddle on your mobile http://jsfiddle.net/hQ34W/show/ and check what value it prints.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use *less than or equal to*.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (screen.width<=240) {
        $('.verybig').hide();
    } else { 
        $('.verybig').show();
    }
});
```

You could refactor this down to this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.verybig').toggle(screen.width > 240);
});
```